# Speed of procedural geometries

Tags: opengl, android, geometry, virtual-reality, procedural

I'm evaluating solutions for creating a VR videogame that should run on cellphones. The assets will be streamed from our servers and that could be a problem on limited capabilities devices.

Since the geometries are not going to be too complex (mostly boxes and wardrobes) I was thinking about procedurally generating them.

Is generating geometries procedurally usually faster or slower than just streaming a bunch of vertex data?

Comment: Compressed vertex data is usually not huge compared to other game assets like textures, sounds, music, and animations. Especially if the meshes are as simple as you describe. Are you sure streaming this data is A) necessary and B) your biggest performance obstacle? Procedurally generating meshes is non-trivial, especially if you want those meshes to look like a variety of real-world objects or have artistic control over the results. Can you describe what root problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @DMGregory sure, I'll add some more details: the VR app I'm designing should run on mobile devices and showcase interiors (think of a restaurant app). The problem with this is: the contents are dynamic (i.e. the rooms might change overnight) so I need to get the data from the server each time (installing stuff locally aside from the player can't ensure all the assets are available each time the app is run).

Comment: In that case you still need to wait for a round-trip response from the server to tell you what procedural meshes to generate (seed parameters etc) and that's likely the slowest part of the process. I wouldn't expect a few kb of mesh data to add any noticeable delay here - at least not one so large that building a whole procedural mesh generation system becomes worthwhile.